# handling multiple requests in Django

Tags: python, django, api, rest

i am new to Django and i am working on a rest API, my Django project is about making appointments with doctors, while each user can only make one appointment with a specific doctor, and each appointment, will have a number determine the order of the user, in a specific date, my question is there's any possible way that two or more users can make the same request,at the same time, and how i will determine the right order for them?
this is my code for creating an appointment

```
def post(self, request, did):
        doctor = get_object_or_404(pk = did)
        appointment_dt = datetime(request.GET['date'])
        if doctor.is_available(appointment_dt):
            date_counter = len(Appointment.objects.filter(doctor, date))
            if doctor.patient_limit < date_counter + 1:
                return Response({'patient_number':'the date is full'}, status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE)
            appointment = Appointment(data = request.GET)
            if appointment.is_valid():
                appointment.save(user = request.user, doctor = doctor)
                return Response(appointment.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({'date':'the doctor is not available at this date'}, status = status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT)
```

Comment: Django processes HTTP requests sequentially. Typically a webserver is configured that runs multiple Django processes, and thus load balances between these processes.

Comment: Normally if you wrap items into transactions, the first view that commits will take the appointment, the second one will then fail to do that, since that transaction conflicts with the other one. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/

Comment: sorry i am a beginner but what i had in mind, is if the first view commits the second one will throw an integrity exception, so all i have to do is to increase the order number, is that's right?